# How can I Create packets of a file in Java

Tags: java, serialization, serial-port

I have to create a program that takes a binary file and transfers it to another device via UART, how can I make packets out of a file.
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far? Any skeleton code with fill-in-the-blanks even?

Comment: no just starting the research part..nyways if you can help thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no packets at the UART level, just byte streams.  If you want to put files in packets, define your own packet format where you add some header bytes (things like filename, size, etc.) followed by file data, and possibly ending with a CRC.  Then you stream your packet on UART and parse it on the other side.

Comment: By packets I meant byte streams sorry for lang problem ,Really new at this...how can i make byte streams?
thanks again